# Error stabilisation control- ESC and engine stopped and wouldn't start again

Tags: vw, dtc, passat

I drive a 2014 2,0 TDI 4w Passat and until now haven't had any problems with the vehicle.
When I drove to work on Friday the vehicle suddenly stoppen in a roundabout and wouldn't start again. Check engine light also went on. After some tries the vehicle started but stopped again several times when I tried to go away from the roundabout (not a good place to have a failure on the vehicle) but after several starts the vehicle started again and was able to run. The check engine light was also turned off in the disply but the cruise didn't work when I drove to work. Vehicle worked all the way to work but when I started the vehicle in the evening again I was just able to drive a few meters and then I got the same failure again and neede to leave the vehicle on the parking lot for the weekend.
Anyone have any idea of what have happend?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Getting any codes read is going to be your first diagnostic effort. Once you get those read, it's going to tell you what might be going on and the direction you should take the repairs.